# Show all column data when filter is left blank

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Two sheets WB1 and WB2

[hope these images will suffice to show how the 2 workbooks(WB) are structured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FkLt.jpg)

I am able to filter the data from WB2 using the dropdown menu filters in WB1 to populate the data to WB1

However, I want to be able to show all possible data from any of the columns when a filter is left blank. e.g:
Country A, Product B  Date: " "

it will show all the Products for Country A across all dates.

Modifying the response from a previous question, I have this code:

```
If WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Cells(2, 10).Text = "" Then WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Cells(2, 10).Text = "*"
```

But it does not work and I get a blank dataset. Researching further, I was able to come up with:

```
.AutoFilter field = 37, Criteria1:=IIf(Trim(Range(WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Cells(2, 10).Text)) = "", "<>", "=") & Range(WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Cells(2, 10)).Text
```

It gives me the error: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I've tried to modify the above codes to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your data structure of the two workbooks is unclear, maybe you can give a more explicit example.

Comment: Edited the question to include viz of WBs used  @Capt.Krusty

Comment: `AutoFilter field = 37` ? .. You are filtering only the first 3 columns? Then, there will be only 3 fields to evaluate. .. Also, I would suggest to use `If-Then` block to apply the filter instead of `IIF` function to change the criteria. What are the addresses of those 3 cells? .. Is it (1,10),(2,10),(3,10)?

Comment: @Naresh - sorry for the confusion. Its just a typo, and should  be 3. However, the formula still holds true as the actual database on WB2 is up to col BC. I only used 3 cols for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1):

If the previous code is working for you then ...

```
Sub filter_by_cell_value()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim WF As WorksheetFunction
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AU06")
    Set WS2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\name\Documents\jbl\Extract.xlsb").Sheets("AU06")
    
    With WS2
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' your own range
            'If you want to check only for the Cells(2, 10) = ""
            If WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Cells(2, 10).Text = "" Then
            'If you want to check if any of those three cells are blank then you can use line below
            'In that case, don't forget to comment out the "If" line above
            'If WF.CountA(WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Range("A10:C10")) <> 3 Then
            'In the line above check the range address
            .Copy
            'Copy all the data
            Else
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=WS1.Parent.Sheets("Appendix 2").Cells(2, 9).Text
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
    With WS1.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```